# that/which causing confusion

Tags: which-that

Can someone please help me to figure out how to write the following sentence:

> Do not make any changes to panels or fixtures that may cause the structure to collapse.

Is this correct? It seems to me that the sentence is saying:

> Do not make any changes to:
>
> - panels
> - fixtures that may cause the structure to collapse

'that may cause the structure to collapse' should be linked to 'changes', but I'm not quite sure how to change the sentence to indicate this.

I've looked online and couldn't find advice on sentences like this.

Comment: The cited construction is syntactically ambiguous, but almost certainly the intended sense is *changes (**to panels or fixtures**) that may cause problems*. That's just "logic".

Comment: No listener could ever hear that it's bad to change "fixtures that may cause the structure to collapse" since we'd all want those changes.

Comment: If the antecedent is intended to be just "fixtures", then insert a comma after "panels". As it stands it's ambiguous.

Comment: In speech it'd be clear and no one would think of the ambiguity. But this is writing and all writing is ambiguous; this is a particularly good example. If you wanna fix it, use two sentences. _The panels and fixtures are fragile. Do not make any changes to them that may cause them to collapse._

Comment: You get to have the fun of rearranging and rewriting.  But proofreading is off topic here.  I guess you could run a new version by people who visit the site chat.

Comment: Do not make any changes, to panels or fixtures, that may cause the structure to collapse.

Answer (score 0):

This way is easier to understand:

"Do not make any changes to panels or fixtures since it may causes the structure to collapse."

Comment: I think this version is worse than the original. What does "it" refer to in your version?

Comment: It here refers to changes.

Comment: since *they may cause" etc.